# HTML change css Style Based on PHP Variable

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php page with html and php in it. I have the following code:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {

    $result = convertTemp($x);

    $tempdesc = getTempName($x);

    $textcolor = "blue";

    echo ($x . " degrees F is equal to " . round($result, 1) . " C, which is " . '<span id="<?php $textcolor ?>" >' . $tempdesc . '</span>' ."<br/>\n");

}
```

I would like to have the variable `tempdesc` echo in different colors based on the `$textcolor` variable above. For now I have it set to "blue" since I have an id set to blue in my css so they should match up and the word should be echoed in blue but the text is not changing color.

Comment: @user3783243 make that an answer and I will accept it. That did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are already in PHP so the `<?php` and `?>` should be removed.
2. A variable in single quotes is the literal text, it is not the variable. In double quotes PHP expands it to the value.
3. Your variable is `$textcolor`, not `$blue`.

Try:

```
echo ($x . " degrees F is equal to " . round($result, 1) . " C, which is " . '<span id="' . $textcolor . '" >' . $tempdesc . '</span>' ."<br/>\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is to change the inline style.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {

    $result = convertTemp($x);

    $tempdesc = getTempName($x);

    $textcolor = "blue";

    echo ("{$x} degrees F is equal to {round($result, 1)} C, which is " . 
'<span style="color:{$textcolor}">' . "{$tempdesc}" . '</span>' ."<br/>\n");

}
```

Make sure to use the curly braces around the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you did not have any variable ($blue)

please replace only this line

```
<span style="color:'.$textcolor.'" >
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using sass ? u can use variable as color or anything in it!